# What does “base passions” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the author mean by **"base passions"** in this sentence? Following sentence is from book "Brain Rules for Baby by John Medina"

> Philosophy titans such as David Hume thought that **base passions** powered moral decisions.

Collins dictionary directed me to a [page](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/base#nav1) with a number of definitions of *base*, noun, which might be relevant here:

> 2A  conceptual structure or entity on which something draws or depends
>   2.1A  foundation or starting point for further work
>   4A  main or important element or ingredient to which other things are added

Way down at the bottom, after entries for the verb, for phrases, for rhymes, for the etymology, and after an advertisement, I eventually discovered  definitions for *base*, adjective:

> 1 Without moral principles; ignoble
>   2 *archaic* Denoting or befitting a person of low social class

I cannot tell which of these meanings is intended.

Comment: base (adj): http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/base_3 -useful?

Comment: base passions = the most rudimentary desires/animal motives

Comment: When you [asked this question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295447/what-does-base-passions-mean), you were asked to do **two** things: (1) Consider if this question would be better on ELL (which you did), and (2) include the research you have done (which you still have not done). Please read through the [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), post, along with the answers below it. There, we explain why at the very least this question should include a couple definitions from an online dictionary. Then, the question could be reopened.

Comment: I think these two words, **base** and **passions**, could prove to be quite elusive  for a person not from a western culture.

Comment: @Stoney - I'm all for helping out new learners. If you could edit this question with one of those definitions, I'll reopen this immediately. This is a case where we can collectively lead by example.

Comment: @TRomano - I agree, I think this could be an excellent question. But an O.P. still needs to convey what has already been found and discovered, so that we don't all go on the same [wild goose chases](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+wild-goose+chase).

Comment: do you completely rule out word's use as *adjective* there? @StoneyB

Comment: @MaulikV It unquestionably **is** an adjective there: 'base passions' is very nearly a fixed phrase in English, one of the few places where adjectival *base* survives in everyday spoken English.

Comment: @J.R. **And** win hats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"base passions" is one of those idioms that you won't really get the meaning of by combining the dictionary definitions of the individual terms. Base passions are the wants of the body: hunger, lust, fear, etc. as opposed to the wants of the mind or the soul: beauty, justice, love.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer :)  I was not able to find its meaning anywhere.

Comment: I disagree. You won't get it from the *ordinary* usage of "base", perhaps, but it's still a "dictionary definition".

Comment: You can cobble together something of an idea from the individual definitions, if you can figure out which combinations apply, but the phrase "base passions" has a long history in western thought going back to Greek and Christian ideas, with a fair bit of social snobbery thrown in. Which passions are base and why? You won't get what Hume is talking about in full without some knowledge of that history.

Answer (score 5):

*Base* here is the adjective, with the meaning "low, ignoble".

*Passions* is used in the sense of "desires, emotions"; the word is etymologically related to *passive* and originally expressed the notion that our desires are somehow separate from our "true selves": they're not under our control, they're forces outside us which compel us to do what we do. (*Emotion* has a similar sense: an emotion is etymologically something which *moves* us.) In most classical philosophies *passion* is opposed to *reason*: the passions are the urges of our "lower", ignoble, animal selves, while reason is the "higher", truly human instrument for dealing with the world.

So the author is claiming that Hume said people do not base their moral decisions on rational considerations but on the irrational promptings of their  desires—hunger, greed, sex, fear, and the like.